# Passing the dynamic id for the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timepicker

I am creating the dynamic text boxes with dynamic id. Now I want to change the dynamic text boxes to the time selecting drop down. I changed my script, but I am getting error like the id is not defined.
Here is my code:

```
<div>
            <input class="btn btn-info" onclick="addtextbox()" type="button" value="Add">
        </div>
```

```
<script>
        var count = 0;
        function addtextbox() {
            count++;
            var newTextBoxDiv = document.createElement('div');
            newTextBoxDiv.id = 'Tools';
            document.getElementById("ToolsGroup").appendChild(newTextBoxDiv);

            newTextBoxDiv.innerHTML = '<form class="form-inline"><div class="form-group"><label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="starttime">Starttime</label><div class="col-md-4"><input type="startime" class="form-control input-md" id="starttime' + count + '" placeholder="starttime" required=""> </div></div>' +
                '<div class="form-group"><label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="endtime">Endtime</label><div class="col-md-4"><input type="endtime" class="form-control input-md" id="endtime' + count + '" placeholder="endtime" required="" onclick="timePicker()"></div></div></form>' +
                '&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Remove" class="removeTools" onclick="removeTextArea(this);">'
            console.log("Iam count", count);
        };

        function removeTextArea(inputElement) {
            var el = inputElement;
            while (el.tagName != 'DIV') el = el.parentElement;
            el.parentElement.removeChild(el);
            count--;
        }

    </script>
```

My time picker script is

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#starttime'+count).timepicker({
                timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
                interval: 30,
                use24hours: true,
                scrollbar: true,
            });
        });
    </script>
```

what i need here is when i click the add button two text boxes will be created and when i click the text box it should display the time in 30 minutes interval of 24 hours format

Comment: Don't use incremental `id` attributes. It's an anti-pattern. Given them all the same `class` then instantiate the `timepicker()` on that class

Comment: @Rory McCrossan ,How do i use the class for time picker funtion. Should I use ``` (".class name").timepicker({}).

Answer (score -1):

Because when page finish load, `my time picker script` run and variable `count = 0` => render function `timepicker` for `id=starttime0` and no have any documentId with name `starttime0`
When you click add button, function  `my time picker script` not rerender then not have action create function  `timepicker` for `id=starttime1,2,3....`